# Quick question: What happens if you set a password of a user signed in with a 3rd party?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

What happens if you set a new password of a user who originally didn't use a password & email combo, but instead a third party like Google?

And another question, should I prevent users from doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link different auth providers to same user with no problem

Sign in the user using any authentication provider or method then Prompt the user for an email address and new password and then Create an AuthCredential object with the email address and password:

```
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

Now pass the AuthCredential object to the signed-in user's linkWithCredential method:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(usercred) {
  var user = usercred.user;
  console.log("Account linking success", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Account linking error", error);
});
```

The call to linkWithCredential will fail if the credentials are already linked to another user account. In this situation, you must handle merging the accounts and associated data as appropriate for your app:

```
// Get reference to the currently signed-in user
var prevUser = auth.currentUser;
// Sign in user with another account
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Sign In Success", user);
  var currentUser = user;
  // Merge prevUser and currentUser data stored in Firebase.
  // Note: How you handle this is specific to your application

  // After data is migrated delete the duplicate user
  return user.delete().then(function() {
    // Link the OAuth Credential to original account
    return prevUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
  }).then(function() {
    // Sign in with the newly linked credential
    return auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Sign In Error", error);
});
```

Check official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).

Answer (score 1):

I have always asked user to sign in with email and password and then provided an option to sign-in with Google account.

But if you want to give email and password sign-in after Google account sign-in  you will have to link the account for which you would have to ask the user to login (to authorise them).

After authorisation I don't see how it will comprise the account.